# How do i get specific value from database in php?

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
    $sql="Select chanceNo From gm_gacha_token1 where token_code='$mytoken'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Langauge: PHP

What i am trying to achieve is that, i want to get a single value of chanceNo.. How can i get the value and store it to cookie/sesison and display it in next page??

Any idea, what is the next step or next line of codes??

Comment: You are using [an obsolete database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page1:

```
session_start();

$query = mysql_query("Select chanceNo From gm_gacha_token1 where token_code='$mytoken' LIMIT 1");

if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$_SESSION['chanceNo'] = $result['chanceNo'];
// done, maybe header('location: page2.php'); ?
} else {
 // no result
}
```

Page2:

```
session_start();
$chanceNo = $_SESSION['chanceNo'];
echo $chanceNo;
```

Comment: Oh by the way, i was not able to display chanceNo on Page2. May i know what is wrong with it?

Comment: Ah, nv mind, sorry for late reply.. it is working already.. Many thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Try this one...

```
   $sql="Select chanceNo From gm_gacha_token1 where token_code='$mytoken' LIMIT 1"; 
   $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

 while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
      echo $rows[chanceNo];
    }
```